# How to access to web page (for example nginx index.html) through a docker container inside a VM on virtualbox

Tags: networking, virtualbox, docker, vagrant, reverse-proxy

I explain my issue, I have a VM create with a VagrantFile who take an IP from my LAN (via bridge).

So admit my VM has an IP (192.168.15.11), in this VM I create 3 docker containers who have an IP  from the docker network.

- 1 containers for nginx (ip : 172.20.0.2)
- 1 containers for traefik (ip: 172.20.0.3)
- 1 containers for portainer (ip: 172.20.0.4)

I can access to the dashboard for my traefik(192.168.15.11:8080) and my portioner(192.168.15.11:9000) containers from my host machine because I expose this port.

But I want to access my Nginx web page on my host machine.

I try to put the following line in the `/etc/hosts` of my VM:

```
192.168.15.11 mynginx.com
```

But it still doesn't work, and I don't know what to do to solve this issue.
Does someone have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify which port you are running nginx on.  In my case I'm running it on port 80.   So I just access as http://VMIP  or http://VMIP/index.html

**docker-compose.yml**

```
  reverse:
    image: nginx:alpine
    container_name: reverse
    restart: unless-stopped
    hostname: reverse
    networks:
      - htpc-network
    environment:
      - PUID=${PUID} # default user id, defined in .env 
      - PGID=${PGID} # default group id, defined in .env
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - ./nginx/html:/usr/share/nginx/html
      - ../static:/usr/share/nginx/static  # get nginx to serve flask static content
      - ${ROOT}/complete:/usr/share/nginx/media # media library
    ports:
      - "80:80"
```